# Liquibase Custom SQL reports success, but is rolled back during spring initialization

Tags: liquibase

My Schema elements are all created successfully, but inserted data is not in the table at the end of the unit test, there is no error reported, but the data is not in the tables after liquibase runs.

```
<changeSet author="gbegley" id="load_default_tags" runAlways="true" failOnError="true">
    <sql>
        insert into po.tags (id,type,description) values (10,'Exclude','Hide Transactions')
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Liquibase outputs the following

```
INFO 11/21/13 10:38 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 11/21/13 10:38 AM:liquibase: Reading from public.databasechangelog
INFO 11/21/13 10:38 AM:liquibase: Reading from public.databasechangelog
INFO 11/21/13 10:38 AM:liquibase: classpath:com/epacube/gpo/db/changelog/changelog.xml:     com/epacube/gpo/db/changelog/tags.xml::load_default_tags::gbegley: Custom SQL executed
INFO 11/21/13 10:38 AM:liquibase: classpath:com/epacube/gpo/db/changelog/changelog.xml:     com/epacube/gpo/db/changelog/tags.xml::load_default_tags::gbegley: ChangeSet com/epacube/gpo/db/changelog/tags.xml::load_default_tags::gbegley ran successfully in 3ms
INFO 11/21/13 10:38 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

However

```
select * from po.tags
```

Returns no results.

I tried using "insert" elements but saw the same results (reported success, but no data).

I pulled the source for lb3.07 from git hub and stepped through with the debugger. Watch the liquibase springLiquibase bean, my insert statements had been executed and were visible in my database table at the end of the SpringLiquibase bean's initialization (after SpringLiquibase#afterPropertiesSet is complete)

However, this all happens during spring container initialization of my junit test. The Junit test itself only runs an assertion that checks the table is not empty, which is failing.

This is liquibase version 3.07 running against postgresql 9.3 using spring 3.2.2 and Junit 4.7

Comment: You probably need a `commit` in your custom sql.

Comment: I was hoping... but after adding a commit their is still no data in target table :/

Comment: @gbegley you find any solution? I am facing with the same problem.